# Django-views Custom filter

Tags: django, django-views

If having different books stored in django database, each book has a date in which it was added to the database. Is their a way of filtering books written by a certain author that was within a date range only using django views?

Comment: you need a view to filter objects? There is many ways to do it, paste a bit of your code.

Comment: items = Order.objects.filter(Q(created_on__range=[start_date, end_date]) ,
    (Q(order_article=user_search))
    )

Comment: not filtering all i want

Comment: If you are trying to do something such as: {% books.filter(start, end) %} that is not possible from the template, and for good reasons! Separation of concerns. However you can look into creating a custom template tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by `only django views`, I assume you want to use querysets. Your question is poorly written - [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And Queryset would be something like this.

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author__name=authors_name, 
                            date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"])
```